# com.lowagie.text.DocumentException: Font 'STSong-Light' with 'UniGB-UCS2-H' is not recognized

Tags: maven, itext

a maven project ,when i want to ctreate a pdf ,happened this:com.lowagie.text.DocumentException: Font 'STSong-Light' with 'UniGB-UCS2-H' is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following fragment of the free ebook [The ABC of PDF with iText](https://leanpub.com/itext_pdfabc):

[image]

As you can see, I create a font 'STSong-Light' with 'UniGB-UCS2-H' as encoding, and I use it to write the Chinese title of the movie "House of The Flying Daggers". You can see that this works perfectly by looking at the screen shot of the PDF.

If it doesn't work for you, then this is what may have gone wrong:

1. You didn't read the documentation (or you wanted to wait until somebody copy/pasted a snapshot of the documentation) which explains why you didn't include the itext-asian.jar into your CLASSPATH. This jar can be found in the [extrajars-2.3.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/files/extrajars/extrajars-2.3.zip/download)
2. Or you did read the documentation, but you didn't include the correct itext-asian.jar into your CLASSPATH. I see that you are using my name in your code (I am the Lowagie from `com.lowagie.text`). This means that you are using a version of iText that has been removed from all official servers years ago. [That version should no longer be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially)

In short: you can solve your problem by upgrading to the latest iText version and making sure that you include the itext-asian.jar.

Answer (score -1):

```
iTextSharp.text.io.StreamUtil.AddToResourceSearch(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("iTextAsian")
)
```